# что не так, Paramiko запуск скрипта на удёлённом Windows сервере

Tags: python, python-3.x, paramiko

Установил OpenSSH на Windows server, через putty подключаюсь всё ок. Локально `python C:\py\1.py` на сервере выполняется. Запускаю скрипт приведённый ниже со своего компа, ошибок никаких не получаю.

```
import sys
import os
import paramiko

print(os.name)

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect('10.10.10.10', username='root', password='root')
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("python C:\py\1.py")

print(stdout.read())
client.close()
sys.exit(0)
```

Вывод всех принтов: `nt b''`
А должен давать вывод этого скрипта `C:\py\1.py` модифицированных файлов.
Что не так? Как получить вывод?

Comment: Читайте stderr, возможно там написана причина проблемы

Comment: @andreymal действительно, прочитал `print(stderr.read().decode('cp866')` и разобрался в чём была проблема, оказывается слэши по чему то ему не нравились в эту сторону `python C:\py\1.py` надо было `python C:/py/1.py`

Comment: В плане слэшей оно возможно хочет `C:\\py\\1.py` потому что просто `\1` это escape-последовательность, которая означает не два этих символа, а байт 01

Comment: @andreymal да так и было, там еще проблема была с пользователем для того на котором тестил не была указана директория PATH. Но в любом случае, даже не подумал прочитать `stderr` без прочтения бы не разобрался) Спасибо